# ASP.NET MVC: Menu in the view not updating even after updating sitemap

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using sitemap to show the menu in the web application(ASP.NET MVC)

I updated sitemap and ran the web application again, but the changes are not seen in the view. I tried "hard reload" and "empty cache and hard reload" in the chrome browser and nothing worked.

How can I see the sitemap changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this by killing the IIS Express([How do I start/stop IISExpress Server ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955696/how-do-i-start-stop-iisexpress-server)) and running the web application again.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the sitemap and master pages in MVC, using the default `_Layout.cshtml` in Shared folder inside Views is much simpler and easier to use.

In the beginning when I switched from ASP.Net Web Forms to ASP.Net MVC, I also tried to stick to sitemap and master pages, however, soon I found out that `_Layout.cshtml` is not too difficult at all. You can still control access by allowing specific users and roles.