# Error while running .Net 1.1 Application in visual studio

Tags: c#, iis-6, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I get the following message when I try to run a .net 1.1 web application in Visual Studio 2003:

> Error while trying to run project.Unable to start debugging on the web server. There is no managed code running in the process. In order to attach a process with the .Net debugger, managed code must be running in the process before attaching.

Can any body tell what I am missing here.

FYI : The application is working fine on the live server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

1. Right click the **ASP.Net project > Properties**
2. select **Configuration Properties > Debugging**
3. Enable the below mentioned entries in '**Debuggers**' frame.

   - **ASP.Net Debugging**
   - **Unmanaged code debugging**.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446756/why-am-i-unable-to-debug-my-asp-net-website-in-visual-studio), as well.

Comment: I have enabled the above two properties but now It get "UnManaged Code debugging is not available" message.