# Unable to attach to the process in Visual Studio 2003

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2003, attach-to-process

I have a legacy WinForms Desktop app made in .NET 1.1 and Visual Studio 2003. This app consists on some executable files that are started in sequence using Process.Start method. Also to communicate each other it is used .NET Remoting.

Now I am debugging the application and I need to attach to a process and stop it at a concrete breakpoint but I cannot attach to it. Some time ago I could attach to this same process without problems but now I cannot. The only difference is that I have recently installed Visual Studio 2017 and TFS... I am not sure if it is the culprit.

In order to attach to a process I follow below steps:

1. From Visual Studio 2003 I navigate to "Debug->Processes..."
2. A "Processes" dialog window is opened and from there a list of processes is shown.
3. From that list I select the process which I want to attach and I click on "Attach" button.
4. "Attach to Process" dialog window is opened a list of programs type to debug is displayed. I select "Common Language Runtime".
   [image]
5. After selecting it I get below message error:
   [image]

I have tried some workarounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855454/error-while-running-net-1-1-application-in-visual-studio) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/59d16b8b-2c46-4e6d-8843-34096546c8be/unable-to-attach-to-the-process-when-debugging-in-vs2003?forum=vsdebug) but without success.

Anyway, debugging was always working without need to make this kind of workarounds and suddenly it has stopped working from one day to the next. I do not understand anything.... The projects are the same and I have not touch anything.

Comment: Can you post your errors in text format?

Comment: Why did you select "Common Language Runtime"? Is that your WinForms app process  name?

Comment: "No managed code" means that process has no .NET code in it. So cannot be a WinForms application.

Comment: @Richard The process I want to attach to is a .NET 1.1 Windows application. Its output type is set to Windows application and it is started using Process.Start.

Comment: If it is a native application that loads .NET later (eg. explorer pligin) then you would need to either wait for the plugin to be loaded before attaching or also enable native debugging (ie. don't depend on .NET being loaded yet at all).

Comment: @Richard Furthermore It was always working and suddenly it stopped working. And from the attach to process  window where a list of processes is shown, the type of the process I want to attach to is displayed as .NET, Win32

Comment: @Richard ok, thanks for your suggestions. I have tried to select only "native" and then the error is not shown but the breakpoint is market "No symbols has been loaded for this document"

Comment: You need to select *both* CLR (aka managed)  and native. This will allow the debugger to operate at both levels.